Which time unit does graphdb's onto:measure uses?
The GraphDB docs states that if i want collect the execution time of a query a should use onto:measure like in the example bellow. However it doesn´t states which time unit it returns neither if the total execution time is the sum of the indivual time of each collection. Does anyone knows this answers and where can i learn more about onto:measure in general?
PREFIX onto: <http://www.ontotext.com/> 
PREFIX gtfs: <http://vocab.gtfs.org/terms#> 
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
SELECT * FROM onto:measure{     
?shape a gtfs:Shape .     
?shape gtfs:shapePoint ?shapePoint.    
?shapePoint geo:lat ?shape_pt_lat .     
?shapePoint geo:long ?shape_pt_lon .     
?shapePoint gtfs:pointSequence ?shape_pt_sequence . 
}

PREFIX gtfs: <http://vocab.gtfs.org/terms#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?shape ?shapePoint ?shape_pt_lat ?shape_pt_lon ?shape_pt_sequence
{
  
  { # ----- Begin optimization group 1 -----
    
    ?shape rdf:type gtfs:Shape . #  Collection size: 956    Predicate collection size: 1,462,787    Unique subjects: 1,462,619  Unique objects: 23  Current complexity: 956
     # EXECUTION: (count:956     totalTime:1       minTime:0       maxTime:0       ownTime:0       externalTime:0)

    ?shape gtfs:shapePoint ?shapePoint . #  Collection size: 354,750    Predicate collection size: 354,750  Unique subjects: 956    Unique objects: 354,750 Current complexity: 354,750
     # EXECUTION: (count:354750  totalTime:203     minTime:0       maxTime:0       ownTime:62      externalTime:140)

    ?shapePoint geo:lat ?shape_pt_lat . #   Collection size: 362,156    Predicate collection size: 362,156  Unique subjects: 362,156    Unique objects: 29,254  Current complexity: 354,750
     # EXECUTION: (count:354750  totalTime:183     minTime:0       maxTime:0       ownTime:61      externalTime:121)

    ?shapePoint geo:long ?shape_pt_lon . #  Collection size: 362,156    Predicate collection size: 362,156  Unique subjects: 362,156    Unique objects: 40,138  Current complexity: 354,750
     # EXECUTION: (count:354750  totalTime:207     minTime:0       maxTime:1       ownTime:62      externalTime:145)

    ?shapePoint gtfs:pointSequence ?shape_pt_sequence . #   Collection size: 354,750    Predicate collection size: 354,750  Unique subjects: 354,750    Unique objects: 1,087   Current complexity: 354,750
     # EXECUTION: (count:354750  totalTime:215     minTime:0       maxTime:1       ownTime:64      externalTime:150)

    
  } # ----- End optimization group 1 -----
  # ESTIMATED NUMBER OF ITERATIONS: 354,750
  
}

# NOTE: Optimization groups are evaluated one after another exactly in the given order.
# If there are too many optimization groups consisting of a single statement pattern,
# then one should try to relocate the following clauses by hand:
# VALUES, BIND, OPTIONAL, property paths with '*' and/or '+' (the latter can be also surrounded with brackets).
# Sub-SELECTs will always be evaluated first.

